# Exercise with the divergence theorem

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

Calculate the outflow of $F = (x, x+y, x+y+z)$ through the sphere centered at the origin and having radius $4$.
I apply the divergence theorem for which I calculate the following triple integral

$\int\int\int_V div(F) dxdydz $

where $div(F) = 3$.

Turning to the spherical coordinates I get

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi \\ 
y= \rho\sin\theta \sin\phi \\ 
z = \rho\cos\phi 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $dx~dy~dz = \rho^2\sin\phi  ~d\rho~d\theta~d\phi$ and $\rho \in [0,1], \theta \in [0, 2 \pi], \phi \in [0, \pi] $

The integral therefore becomes

$ \displaystyle 3 \int_0^4 \rho^2 ~d\rho \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\pi}\sin^2 \phi ~d\phi ~$ and the result is $64\pi^2$.

I'm not sure I did the calculations correctly

Comment: Why do you have $\sin^2\phi$ in the integral? The answer is $3$ times the volume of the sphere which is $256 \pi$ given radius is $4$

Comment: The last integral, over $\phi$ should be just $\sin$, not $\sin^2$

Comment: If the divergence is constant and you know that the integral is just the volume of the sphere, can you think of a way to check this yourself?

Comment: Writing $sin^2$ instead of $sin$ was the mistake that didn't lead me to the result. I didn't realize ...thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the divergence is a constant, the integral over the volume is just multiplication by the volume. The volume of a sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$
So you should be getting $ 4^4 \pi = 2^8 \pi = 256 \pi$

Comment: It's true, thanks but I wanted to understand what I was wrong in calculating the integral. I had made a copying mistake